# React App Failing to Deploy to Github Pages: Error 404

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment

I am trying to deploy a react app to github pages but every time I deploy, I get the error 404 messages below. I manually added my build folder to my repository and tried updating the PUBLIC_URLs in my index.html but that hasnt helped. Does anyone know whats going wrong? Here is the link to my repository: https://github.com/SamMathewson98/Combat-Customs-QC-Retry

and here are the errors I get:
main.55ef6566.js:1

```
   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

main.0dccaaf5.css:1

```
   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

manifest.json:1

```
   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
main.0dccaaf5.css:1

```
   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

manifest.json:1

```
   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

Comment: Try to modify homepage attribute of the package.json file like this : https://SamMathewson98.github.io/Combat-Customs-QC-Retry" once